# Redirect to another URL after login

Tags: android, cookies

My program will ask for the username and password of the student, and after a successful login it will get the picture and name of the student from the HTML source code of the main page and display it on another intent or activity.

It's working well but I want to view the HTML source code of another page, but I don't know how. Every time I create another httpclient or httpost to visit another page it shows the source code of the login page even if I'm already logged in.

This is the main code:

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  String uname, pass, pic;
  EditText txtUname, txtPass;
  Button login;
  TextView result, tview2, tview3;
  String nameStartLine = " <td style=\"font:10px verdana; color:#312e25; text-align:right;\">Name:</td>";
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tview2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tview3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txtUname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    txtPass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  public void postLoginData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm");
    try {
      String username = txtUname.getText().toString();
      String password = txtPass.getText().toString();
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
      result.setText(str);
      Intent intent = new Intent(TestingActivity.this,panel_1.class);
      intent.putExtra("result",result.getText());
      pic = "http://teachers.usls.edu.ph/student_pics/" + txtUname.getText() + ".jpg";
      intent.putExtra("pic",pic);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try{
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals(nameStartLine)) {
          line = rd.readLine();
          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ">< ");
          String marker = st.nextToken();
          while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if(marker.equals("strong")) {
              marker = st.nextToken();
              while(!(marker.equals("/strong"))) {
                total.append(marker + " ");
                marker = st.nextToken();
              }
            }
            marker = st.nextToken();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
  }
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == login){ postLoginData(); }
  }
}
```

And here's the second activity:

```
public class panel_1 extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtresult);
    result.setText(""+getIntent().getExtras().getString("result"));
    //set position
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("pic"));
  }
}
```

As you can see, the program passed the parameters to [`http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm`](http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm). After a sucessful login it will get the HTML source code of the main page, where I get the name and picture of the student. So how can I redirect the program to [this link](http://students.usls.edu.ph/modules/modules.class_schedule.cfm) and view its HTML source code, so that I could get the important datas from it? I tried using `httpclient` again but it shows the HTML source code of the login page or [`http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm`](http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm) even though I'm already logged in.

Comment: Is `result.setText(str);` displays correct source code?

Comment: Is there any special requirement for getting data using web request then show it in `TextView`? Means why are you not using `WebView` directly?

Comment: textview is for showing the name of the student and WebView is for showing the picture of the student

@so geek
yes. it displays the correct source code of the main page. actually the result textview is hidden in the first activity and it's content is forwarded to the 2nd activity which is the panel_1.

Comment: what do you mean by content? Is the second activity's `result.setText(""+getIntent().getExtras().getString("result"));` correctly displays the `result` passed from the first activity?

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity you are making all new request to the server, which is not having any idea about the authentication credentials, hence it returns the login page. Therefore, however you need to pass the `username` and `password` for the second request also.

You need to use [postUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29)

for eg.

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pic");
String postData = username=my_username&password=my_password;
webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

I feel your code was wrong in the following places of first activity

```
intent.putExtra("result",result.getText()); // result.getText().toString();
pic = "http://teachers.usls.edu.ph/student_pics/" + txtUname.getText() + ".jpg"; // txtUname.getText().toString();
```

And, i would suggest you to use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for some advanced functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. After a successful login at http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm, i grabbed the cookies like this

```
   List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
             if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("ERROR","no cookies received");
             } 
             else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    if(cookies.get(i).getName().contentEquals("CFID")) {
                         CFID = cookies.get(i).getValue();
                     }
                    else if(cookies.get(i).getName().contentEquals("CFTOKEN")) {
                         CFTOKEN = cookies.get(i).getValue();
                     }

                }
             }
```

then I called another httppost using this link http://students.usls.edu.ph/modules/modules.class_schedule.cfm to view it's source code.

```
             HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("http://students.usls.edu.ph/modules/modules.class_schedule.cfm");
             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
             nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CFID",CFID));
             nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CFTOKEN",CFTOKEN));
             httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));
```

and finally i managed to view the source code of the http://students.usls.edu.ph/modules/modules.class_schedule.cfm.